# jlabel to display clicked item at JList

Tags: java, swing

How do I make a JLabel display whatever was clicked at JList? Been looking around for examples but to no avail. Has this got to do with event listening? An explicit example is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). It has an example that shows how to write a `ListSelectionListener` that you should be able to modify for your purposes.

The Swing tutorial is full of examples so I suggest you bookmark the Table of Contents for future reference.

Comment: thank you i appr it agn. However I did look @ your suggestion prior to asking this question, but am looking for specific working examples due to time constraint.

Comment: could u pls kindly direct me to 1 specific example if you know of any? the only quite understandable example i found was @ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3ma0jrs7js but still i have not achieved my goal yet. thanks!

Comment: `but am looking for specific working examples due to time constraint.` a time constraint is not our problem, we are not here to write code for you because you don't learn anything that way. Anyway I did point you to a working example that you only need to modify a little bit. Instead of enabling/disabling a button all you need to do is set the text of the label. It can't get any more basic than that. Also this is not a chat site, use proper spelling.